# dygraph set x axis max value and update the dygraph

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Trying to set the maximum value of the x-axis of a dygraph after it has been drawn.
Tried

```
axes = g.axes_;
axes.maxxval = maxVal;
g.updateOptions({
 axes
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to be setting the [`valueRange`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#valueRange) property. See [this demo](http://dygraphs.com/tests/zoom.html).

The trailing `_` in `g.axes_` means it's a private internal property. Nothing good will come from messing with it.